Recommendation of Books on Meijer G and Fox H functions
Which books would you recommend for someone who is a PhD student in engineering and not a mathematician, who wants to understand Meijer G and Fox H functions in depth? By "in depth" I mean not only know how to apply the existing integration theorems but also be able to prove new ones.
For example, I need to calculate the integral of the multiplication of three meijer G functions where one of them has its argument shifted by constant $c$. I could not find any integration identities in the Mathematica documentation or in integral tables such as "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by Alan Jeffrey and Daniel Zwillinger or "Integrals and Series" by Prudnikov and Brychkov.
$\int_0^{\infty}x^{t}G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(x+c\left|\begin{smallmatrix}\mathbf{a},\\
\mathbf{b}\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)G_{r,s}^{t,u}\left(x\left|\begin{smallmatrix}\mathbf{c},\\
\mathbf{d}\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)G_{w,z}^{v,y}\left(x\left|\begin{smallmatrix}\mathbf{e},\\
\mathbf{f}\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)dx$
Therefore, I need to come out with my own solution to this expression.
